# NGINX 403 in Windows 10

Tags: nginx

I am having a crazy time getting NGINX to serve basic css/js files from Windows 10.  I keep getting 403 forbidden. Here is my nginx.conf:
    #user nobody;

```
worker_processes 4;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
 default_type application/octet-stream;
     sendfile on;
     keepalive_timeout 65;
     gzip on;

include /inetpub/wwwroot/T2A_WEBSITE/STOCKS/otics/bokeh/static;
include C:/inetpub/wwwroot/T2A_WEBSITE/STOCKS/otics/bokeh/nginx-
1.12.1/conf/sites-enabled/*.conf;   
}

PROXY file:
server { 
listen 5500; error_log C:/CORE_FILES/nginxlog/error.log debug; 
location /{ 
    include /inetpub/wwwroot/T2A_WEBSITE/STOCKS/otics/bokeh/nginx-1.12.1‌​
           /conf/mime.types; 
    location ~ \.css { add_header Content-Type text/css; } 
    location ~ \.js { add_header Content-Type application/x-javascript; }   
    location ~ ^/(\d+)/static { alias /nginx-1.12.1/html/$1/static; 
    #try_files $uri favicon.ico;    
    } 
    }   
    }
```

Comment: I am seriously wondering if anyoen has gotten NGINX to work as a reverse proxy on Windows 10.  I am using NGINX 1.12.1

Comment: Please add any code you have in the question, don't post it as a comment. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46518520/edit) your own posts.

Comment: Hi, I added the proxy file.